# Manage focusing multiple TextInputs in react-native (more than 10+)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In my React Native application, there will be many TextInputs, and when the user presses the return button, I want react to focus on the next TextInput. Previous stackoverflow threads recommend using refs, but only have examples for 2 TextInputs. What would be the most efficient way to create lets say 30+ refs and handle focusing?

React Native 0.59 w/ regular old js.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this plugin 
https://github.com/gcanti/tcomb-form-native
It allow me to pass inputs as Array, Thus it can be easy manipulate the array and set the focus dynamically.
You can do the following, First install the library

```
npm install tcomb-form-native
```

Then import the library and set your input

```
var t = require('tcomb-form-native');
var Person = t.struct({
  name: t.String,              // a required string
  surname: t.maybe(t.String),  // an optional string
  age: t.Number,               // a required number
  rememberMe: t.Boolean        // a boolean
});
```

Now you can customize fields options through an array. Note I just add a key called "next" this will allow me to loop through the array and focus on the next input dynamically in `componentDidMount`

```
let options = {
  fields: {
    name: {
      returnKeyType: "next",
      next: "surname"
    },
    surname: {
      returnKeyType: "next",
      next: "age"
    },
    age: {
      returnKeyType: "next",
      next: "rememberMe"
    },
    rememberMe: {
      returnKeyType: "done",
      next: "rememberMe"
    }
  }
};
```

Now here is the magic, We just need to loop on the array and dynamically add the focus function for each input

```
Object.keys(options.fields).forEach(function(key) {
   if ("next" in options.fields[key]) {
    if (key == options.fields[key]["next"]) {
      //set the blur in case the input is the last input
      options.fields[key].onSubmitEditing = () => {
       self.refs["form"].getComponent(key).refs.input.blur();
     };
    }else{
      //set the next focus option
      options.fields[key].onSubmitEditing = () => {
       self.refs["form"].getComponent(options.fields[key]["next"]).refs.input.focus();
     };
    }
   }
 })
self.setState({
 options: options
});
```

and then in the render section you should be able to pass fields and options

```
 <Form
  ref="form"
  type={Person}
  options={this.state.options}
  value={this.state.value}
/>
```

This should work dynamically, without worry about how much inputs do you have.

Hopefully this answer your question!

Answer (score 0):

```
// i have a form handler class which does it this is its code.

import React, { Component } from "react";
import { getKeyboardType, isInputValid, isSecureTextEntry } from "./Utils";

class Form extends Component {
  childReferences = [];
  childDetails = [];

  /* go through each input and check validation based on its type */
  checkValidation = () => {
    let isValid = true;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.childReferences.length; i++) {
      if (
        this.childReferences[i].getValue &&
        !isInputValid(
          this.childReferences[i].getValue(),
          this.childDetails[i].type
        )
      ) {
        this.childReferences[i].setError &&
          this.childReferences[i].setError(true);
        isValid = false;
      }
    }
    return isValid;
  };

  /* collecting user entered values from all inputs */
  getValues = () => {
    let data = {};
    this.childReferences.forEach((item, index) => {
      data[this.childDetails[index].identifier] = item.getValue();
    });
    return data;
  };

  onSubmitForm = () => {
    return this.checkValidation() ? this.getValues() : undefined;
  };

  refCollector = ref => this.childReferences.push(ref);

  collectChildDetails = childProps =>
    this.childDetails.push({
      identifier: childProps.identifier,
      type: childProps.type
    });

  /* handling onSubmit of each input when user moves to next input from keyboard */
  onSubmitEditing = index => ev => {
    if (
      index < this.childReferences.length - 1 &&
      this.childReferences[index + 1].setFocus
    ) {
      this.childReferences[index + 1].setFocus();
    }
  };

  render() {
    const wrappedChildrens = [];

    React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child, index) => {
      if (!child) {
        return;
      }
      /* holding details of input in an array for later user */
      this.collectChildDetails(child.props);

      /* cloning children and injecting some new props on them */
      wrappedChildrens.push(
        React.cloneElement(child, {
          key: child.props.identifier || `${child.props.type}_${index}`,
          ref: this.refCollector,
          onSubmitEditing: this.onSubmitEditing(index),
          returnKeyType:
            index < this.props.children.length - 1 ? "next" : "done",
          keyboardType: getKeyboardType(child.props),
          secureTextEntry: isSecureTextEntry(child.props)
        })
      );
    });

    return wrappedChildrens;
  }
}

export default Form;



// this is how its used

<Form ref={ref => (this.formHandler = ref)}>
          <MaterialInput
            label="Emial address"
            error="Enter a valid email"
            rightImage={Images.forwardArrow}
            type={INPUT_TYPES.EMAIL}
            identifier="email"
            blurOnSubmit={false}
          />
          <MaterialInput
            label="Password"
            error="Password length must be greater then six"
            rightImage={Images.forwardArrow}
            type={INPUT_TYPES.PASSWORD}
            identifier="password"
          />
        </Form>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the preferred solution. No need to use external libraries (which may not be maintained in the future) or manually manage a ton of refs.